# $f(x,y)= e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$ when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

let $f(x,y)= e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$ when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

Then

(1) $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

(2) $f$ is continuous but the first order partial derivative does not exists

(3) $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ , first order partial derivative exists but not differentiable

(4) differentiable .

I think only (2) is correct .

Reasoning :

set $r=x \cos \theta ,y=r \sin \theta $. Then as $(x,y)\to (0,0$) we have $r\to 0$ . so $ \lim_{r\to 0} f=\lim _{r\to} e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}=0 . $ but 
$\lim\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)=}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{h^2}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{he^{\frac{1}{h^2}}}$ does not exists as it becomes unbounded .

So the first order prtial derivatives does not exists .Hence it is not differentiable .

is my solution correct ?

Comment: You should have $he^{1/h^2}$ in the denominator, not $he^{-1/h^2}$, right?  And why do you think that's unbounded?

Comment: Yes you correct . I have edited it accordingly . Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The first partial derivative with respect to $x$ (or $y$) at $(0,0)$ is given by

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{h^2}}-0}{h}=\lim_{k\to \infty}ke^{-k^2}=0$$

So, the first partial derivatives exist at the origin.

To see if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ we evaluate the limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(0+h,0+k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}
&=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{h^2+k^2}}-0-0-0}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r}=0
\end{align}$$

So, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and the value of the derivative is $0$.

Comment: Those partials in the numerator should be multiplied by $h,k.$

Comment: @zhw. They are now.  Ah the dangers of using a phone to type a solution ... old eyes on a small screen