# Is f(x) differentiable at (0,0)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

[image: Question]

I think that f(x,y) is continuous at (0,0) and has partial order derivatives but is also differentiable at (0,0) because curve is smooth,ie-  answer is option D ?
Am i correct ?

Comment: Why do you think so? What have you tried?

Comment: if x and y both tend to (0,0) then e^-(1/0) tendes to e^-infinity which is zero. Also we have partial derivates for f(x,y) but at (0,0) f(x,y) seems smooth. So answer shoud be D ?

Comment: What makes it seem smooth? Did you look at a graph of the function, or some kind of numerical investigation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f(x,y)= e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$ when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271809/fx-y-e-frac1x2y2-when-x-y-neq-0-0-and-f0-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct. Option A definitely not correct. For option B, it supposed to have first order partial derivative. For option C, the first order partial derivative is differentiable at (0,0). So, option D has the best and general answer for the question.